# Restrict query to get all items with specific pointer (JavaScript - Parse.com)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, collections

```
BlogApp.Collections.Blogs = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: BlogApp.Models.Blog,
    query: (new Parse.Query(BlogApp.Models.Blog)).equalTo("author", "xMQR0A1Us6").descending('createdAt').limit(9)
});
```

The above doesn't seem to work. I can do all sorts of things with columns that already exist in the class, such as `.equalTo("productType", "SHIRT")`, for example, but I can't link to the author which exists in a separate class User.

How can I restrict the query to retrieve only items from "author" (a pointer) equal to an objectId which exists in the User class?

**Model:**

```
BlogApp.Models.Blog = Parse.Object.extend('MarketDesign', {

    update: function(form) {

        if ( !this.get('ACL') ) {
            var blogACL = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current());
            blogACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
            this.setACL(blogACL);
        }

        BlogApp.category.id = form.category;

        this.set({
            'title': form.title,
            'url': form.title.toLowerCase()
            .replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'')
            .replace(/ +/g,'-'),
            'category': BlogApp.category,
            'comment': form.content,
            'author': this.get('author') || Parse.User.current(),
            'authorName': this.get('authorName') || Parse.User.current().get('username'),
            'time': this.get('time') || new Date().toDateString()
        }).save(null, {
            success: function(blog) {
                Parse.history.navigate('#/admin', { trigger: true });
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(blog, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found that you can't use the .equalTo method to query an element in the pointed-to class: https://coderwall.com/p/-uzbrq/multi-dimensional-querying-parse-com-javascript-sdk

This isn't the answer because it doesn't solve my problem, but hopefully somebody else will see this and have a better picture of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
BlogApp.Collections.UserDesigns = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: BlogApp.Models.Blog,
    query: (new Parse.Query(BlogApp.Models.Blog)).matchesQuery("author", Parse.User.current().id).descending('createdAt').limit(3)
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to find Blogs where the blog author is the *current user*?  That's easy (and described in the first part of my answer).  The other part of my answer dealt with the id `xMQR0A1Us6` in the OP.  What user does that id belong to and where did you get it? I've edited my answer to clarify.  To query for author == current user, the code you've put in this answer is sooo close.  The point is, we pass *objects* to compare with pointer fields.

Comment: Also, the post you site deals with a more complex problem than you're trying to solve here.  What you want to do is common and easy, once you get the hang of how to handle pointers.

Comment: The Id starting with X is just the object Id of a random User. I was testing  different queries. The query is going to be used for the user's profile, displaying all their posts. So at least when viewing your own, you will want the current User's objectId.

Comment: Try current user for starters with the code in my (edited) answer.  That should show you that it works (if you have blogs by the current user).  Then we'll deal with random users next.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, that worked perfectly. What I didn't realize is that I can't just query the "string" that appears in the column, because the value that appears is not a string, per se, but an identifier connecting the classes. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There's a distinction between objectId -- which is just a string -- and a pointer.  To equate a Pointer column in a query, you must pass a parse object.  So, for example, to find Blogs where author is the current user...

```
var user = Parse.User.current();   // no .id, that's important!
BlogApp.Collections.Blogs = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: BlogApp.Models.Blog,
    query: (new Parse.Query(BlogApp.Models.Blog)).equalTo("author", user).descending('createdAt').limit(9)
});
```

If you have only the objectId, then build an object with it, like this:

```
var user = Parse.User.createWithoutData("xMQR0A1Us6");
```

But I don't recommend this.  If you have an object id, you must have once had the whole object to which it belongs.  In general, make it a practice to *not* retain object ids; instead, keep the objects they belong to so that you can use any part of them later.

Comment: Would there be any general reasons as to why this line: ``var user = Parse.User.createWithoutData("xMQR0A1Us6");`` just flat out kills my app?

Comment: That's how to make a user from an id. Surprised  that it causes a crash

Comment: I get ``TypeError: Parse.user is undefined`` in my console.

Comment: User has an uppercase U.

Comment: Does that actually matter given that user is just a variable we've defined?

Comment: The U in Parse.User. That's the class name exported by parse.

Comment: I agree, but I never put that anywhere in my code. It's always capitalized. Not sure why the console is spitting that out.

Comment: Hmm.  I never confront this problem because I never deal with object ids.  I meant to emphasize this in my answer.  The fact that you have an id means that someplace previously, you had the complete object and made the mistake (in my opinion) of keeping only the id.  Can you tweak your code to start with the actual object, not just an id?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm basically pulling this one class (blogs), and one of the columns is connected to another class via a pointer. This pointer column is a list of ids that are attached to a user object. It wouldn't make sense to pull the user object in its entirety. I just need to query the blogs by a particular user id, so that I'm only displaying the blogs belonging to a single user.

Comment: You say "via a pointer".  In the following sentence you say "a list of ids".  A pointer would be good, an array of pointers would be good, a relation would be good... but a list of ids (strings) would be bad.

Comment: This is my table. This should clear things up: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eoX1k.png

Comment: That's good, no object ids kept as strings.  But that's the class you are  querying, right? For the point I'm making, we need to understand where you are getting the user objectId that is the operand to the query.

Comment: Yes, the class I'm querying is MarketDesign as seen in the table. I guess I'm still very new to this so don't fully understand all the terminology. What do you mean by "where are you getting the user objectId"? I've updated my question to show my model.